# gethostname of Windows Server in EC2

Tags: c++, c, winapi, amazon-ec2

I try to write a C/C++ function (multi-platform support) to be able to get the "computer host name" and if it worked very well on "real" workstation or server, it look like it doesn't work on Windows server running in Amazon EC2.

under windows I use the following code:

```
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

char name[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = "";
int size = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH;
::gethostname(name, size);
string hostname(name);

WSACleanup();
```

On windows server in EC2, I get an empty string. but if just check the environment variable, I got:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME%
WIN-LXKBCSPP55Y
```

I also tried `GetComputerName` but it returned `∩½ÿ<Ω▒ìτÅ¡`

Any help would be welcome because for now I don't understand what's happen !

Comment: Try `GetComputerNameA` instead of `GetComputerName`. And don't cast strings to fix compile errors.

Comment: I already tried and anyway I can't because I need to deal with any hostname (Chinese, Russian...), but I found a workaround with _wgerenv